# How do you retrieve last day's of data from Oracle table?

Tags: oracle

I have an oracle database that I like to retrieve last days or last 10 minutes data:

I am ussing this command first:

```
alter session set nls_date_format='dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'
```

Then this:

```
select TIMESTAMP, TARGET_NAME, TARGET_TYPE, COLUMN_LABEL, VALUE, KEY_VALUE from METRIC_TABLE where TIMESTAMP > sysdate -1
```

This command is not giving me last days of data, it only gives me last couple hours of data. I suspect that TIMESTAMP column is not in Oracle datatime format.

Is there a way to format TIMESTAMP to Oracle timestamp format before doing this:

```
TIMESTAMP>SYSDATE -1
```

Comment: Why do you have to guess? Can't you look at your schema?

Comment: @PM77-1, I cannot it is not my database. I dont have the rights.

Comment: @user1471980:   DESC metric_table;   or    select dump(timestamp) from metric_table where rownum = 1;  or   select * from all_tables where table_name = 'METRIC_TABLE';   If you can run your query above, you can certainly see the table definition.

Comment: @Ditto, DESK metric_table shows my TIMESTAMP column is DATE. But when I do where TIMESTAMP >SYSDATE-1, I only get couple hours of data. I should get a day worth of data.

Comment: Then use Ollie's answer below.

Comment: It could be the application putting data in the table is truncating the time portion of the "TIMESTAMP" -- if so, if you run your query at different times of the day, you could get different answers.  Or the server timezone is different from your timezone.

Comment: What do you get if you do `SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') when, sessiontimezone  FROM DUAL`  ? This will tell you your timezone setting

Comment: @OllieJones, I get the same value for all rows: 06-FEB-2015 17:45:43

Comment: ALL ROWS?  That was a one-row query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presuming your `TIMESTAMP` column contains an ordinary date/time variable:

```
SELECT whatever FROM table WHERE TIMESTAMP >= SYSDATE -1
```

gets everything that's newer than 24 hours ago.

```
SELECT whatever FROM table WHERE TIMESTAMP >= SYSDATE - (10.0 / 1440.0)
```

gets everything that's newer than ten minutes ago.

```
SELECT whatever FROM table WHERE TIMESTAMP >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

gets everything newer than midnight last night.

```
SELECT whatever FROM table WHERE TIMESTAMP >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) -1
                             AND TIMESTAMP < TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

gets everything from yesterday.

**Edit** Pro tip: don't use reserved words, like `TIMESTAMP`, for column names.

Try figuring out how many records you have for each hour in the last 5 days like this:

```
 SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(timestamp, 'HH24'), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') hr,
        COUNT(*)
   FROM METRIC_TABLE
  WHERE timestamp >= TRUNC(sysdate) -5
  GROUP BY TRUNC(timestamp, 'HH24')
```

That will help you understand what timestamp values you have in your database.

Comment: @Olilie Jones, I try to convert the TIMESTAMP as follows:select cast(TIMESTAMP as TIMESTAMP) as TIMESTAMP from table name where TIMESTAMP>SYSDATE-1, I still get couple hours worth of data.

Comment: Why CAST ? Ollie's answer didn't use CAST ? don't add to the answer. ;)  And perhaps if you show a small sample of what you have, we could see what you're doing wrong ;) Trust us ... what Ollie put will work .. just copy/past his WHERE clause into your query  (on another note, using a column named "TIMESTAMP" probably isn't the best of ideas :P )